# Sharing text on Facebook programatically IOS is not possible now

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sharing

I cannot able to share text on Facebook programatically in swift.
See my code please.
Here is it,

```
     let facebookPostAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share on Facebook", style:              UIAlertActionStyle.Default) 

       { (action) -> Void in

        if      SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
            let facebookComposeVC = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

            facebookComposeVC.setInitialText("\(self.noteTextview.text)")

            self.presentViewController(facebookComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            self.showAlertMessage("You are not connected to your Facebook account.")
        }

    }
```

This function at the end says to me on run

> facebook share is invalidated

What should I do with this?

Comment: Be aware that prefilling the message is not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has changed policy of sharing, so you need to use their SDK for sharing.
Now developers need to install FBSDKShareKit.framework, and simple add button with context information.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Simple says, you need to add **FBSDKShareButton**, by the way it extends from UIButton, and set context data to it:

```
_fbButton = FBSDKShareButton()
...
// setup visual part
// don't need to add target, facebook's sdk decides action
...
// set context data to shareContent button's property
let fbContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
fbContent.contentURL = value.contentURL
fbContent.contentTitle = value.contentTitle
fbContent.contentDescription = value.contentDescription
fbContent.imageURL = value.imageURL
_fbButton.shareContent = fbContent
```

That's all, facebook's share panel will show with included data after touch up inside this button.

Comment: You meant I should first make a button and and IBOutlet as _fbButton , then doing the above stuff.

Comment: You can change your UIButton which calls UIAlertController, into described in post.

Comment: I haven't understood dear

Comment: `_fbButton.shareContent = fbContent `

Comment: @M.AsimKhan `_fbButton` is variable of instantiated FBSDKShareButton. Or what is the your question?

Comment: Yes this works ..... but I'm still targeted with a disgusting problem, that is I cant post some text just at the top start of my facebook post.

Comment: @M.AsimKhan, you need to fill data of `fbContent`

Comment: ,You'r right! But fbContent has many of its properties. Like contentTitle, contentURL, contentDescription etc but these all are related to the link provided .... I'm talking about the TEXT that might come above the link.

Comment: @M.AsimKhan, in docs says. Pay attention on `contentDescription` property.

Comment: Yeh, I've worked on showing screen shots, and is working fine.

Comment: Yeh, I've worked on showing screen shots, and is working fine. But one thing very unpredictable to me, is that I've scrolling text on my screen and I mean to that large text .... so to show screen picture will not show that all text.

Comment: @M.AsimKhan, it's another question, it has no relation to this topic.

Comment: Now you mean to have one new question for that!

Comment: @AasimKhan, of course create specific question, if you need subject answer ;)

Comment: If you please help me that fbContent.contentURL and fbContent.imageURL both at the same time can work either in the way, the post must go for the content to contentURL and the image must be taken from the imageURL.

Comment: @AasimKhan, hi, create question generally.

Answer (score 3):

Posting with pre-filled text is not allowed as per the Facebook policy. Check this out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Answer (score 1):

You can share the text.

```
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        fbShare.title="share"
        self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: What we do inside else condition ? I got this error `SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType com.apple.social.facebook returning 0
`